# do_shortcode: Opening and Closing tag with variable inside between quotes

Tags: php, wordpress, quotes, shortcode

can you help me fix this code?
It's supposed to get the Product ID (which it does), then get the Custom Field called "ID_del_curso" (which it does), and finally, print out a shortcode [student course_id="$courseid"]HTML[/student]

The button is displaying for anyone who accesses the site, not just the people who qualify as a student of the Course number embedded inside the Product.

I'm guessing the error is where the "echo" line is... I'm going crazy over here! Help!!! Thanks so much :D

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $postid = $product->get_id();
    $courseid = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ID_del_curso', true );
    $html = '<center><div class="alreadyPurchased"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap paddingRightM"></i> Ya te has registrado</div></center>';
    echo do_shortcode("[student course_id=&quot;" .$courseid. "&quot;]". $html . "[/student]"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I kept on trying and resolved it like this:

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $postid = $product->get_id();
    $courseid = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ID_del_curso', true );
    $html = '"]<center><div class="alreadyPurchased"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap paddingRightM"></i> Ya te has registrado</div></center>';
    $openIT = '[student course_id="';
    $closeIT = '[/student]';
    echo do_shortcode( $openIT . $courseid . $html . $closeIT ); 
?>
```

Is there a simpler/clearner way of doing this? Hope it helps anyone trying to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $courseid = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ID_del_curso', true );

    $student = <<<EOD
[student course_id="$courseid"]
    <center>
        <div class="alreadyPurchased">
            <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap paddingRightM"></i> Ya te has registrado
        </div>
    </center>
[/student]
EOD

    echo do_shortcode( $student );
?>
```

This is functionally equivalent to your code but I think easier to read as it is formatted like HTML.